Transferring /dedicating merit
Is dedicating merit the same as transferring merit?! How do the 4 Immeasurables fit in (or do they?) And did the Buddha actually teach any of this?
I know this is three questions, but they all seem connected to me.

Is dedicating merit the same as transferring merit?!
The dedication of merit is the same as transferring merit since we are performing the dana on behalf of the deceased. They are the reason why the dana was performed in the first place. The relevant Pali sutra is the Petavatthu while the associated Mahayana sutra is the Yulanpen. Note that in both traditions, the dedication/transfer of merit only works for beings in the peta realm i.e. the realm of the hungry ghosts. I recalled once a monk saying that the bad karma of those in the hell realms are just too heavy for them to enjoy this merit transfer.
How do the 4 Immeasurables fit in (or do they?)
As far as I know, they don’t. However, in an essay: No Strings Attached, Venerable Thanissaro described that we can repay the kindness of our teachers (likewise our parents) by practicing well. In addition, we honoured our teachers and parents through our noble actions and behaviour.
did the Buddha actually teach any of this
Not verbatim but from the Advice to the Kalamas (AN3:66), the Dharma is to be verified and validated. It is thanks to the help, support and benefits received from those who cared for us that we are what we are today. By association, our good deeds and actions are possible as a result of these people. Thus, they too will benefit from our good merits by logical extension.

Thank you for such a thoughtful answer.  The links are very helpful.

may our relatives living and dead be happy.

The Dhamma as a Refuge is defined in the Pali suttas as follows:

svākkhāto bhagavatā dhammo
The Dhamma is well explained by the Blessed One
sandiṭṭhiko
directly visible; self-evident
akāliko
immediately effective
ehipassiko
inviting inspection; verifiable; lit: 'come & see'.
opaneyyiko
leading onwards
paccattaṁ veditabbo viññūhi
personally/individually to be verified/experienced by the wise

If the above is not understood, one cannot be a real Buddhist.
It follows we cannot know if the Buddha taught anything, apart from what is directly visible & can be inwardly verified.
The above said, at least the sutta DN 31 instructs giving on behalf of others, which is similar to the dedication of merits.

atha vā pana petānaṁ kālaṅkatānaṁ
After the departed (parents) have passed away
dakkhiṇaṁ anuppadassāmīti
I’ll make an offering/dedicate merits on their behalf.


Thank you so much.
